# How to invoke multiple services for a flux / mono in java reactive?

Tags: java, mono, microservices, spring-webflux, flux

I am new to reactive world, might sound a newbee, I have a flux of product having size 20-30, and for each product i need to fetch the below from different microservices:

1. average review count
2. totalCommentCount
3. wishlistedCount
4. variants..
5. ..
   6 ..

What i have tried..

**1. doOnNext**

```
Flux<Product> products = ...
products
.doOnNext(product -> updateReviewCount)
.doOnNext(product -> updateTotalCommentCount)
.doOnNext(product -> updateWishlistedCount)
.doOnNext(product -> updateVariants)
...
```

This turns out to block the chain for each call for each product..

```
e.g.
Total records(20) * No. of service calls(5) * Time per service calls(30 ms) = 3000ms
```

**But time will grow with the number of records || number of service calls.**

**2. map**
using map i updated and returned same reference, but the results were same.

**3. collected all as list and executed aggregate query to downstream services**

```
Flux<Product> products = ...
products
.collectList() // Mono<List<Product>>
.doOnNext(productList -> updateReviewCountOfAllInList)
.doOnNext(productList -> updateFieldB_ForAllInList)
.doOnNext(productList -> updateFieldC_ForAllInList)
.doOnNext(productList -> updateFieldD_ForAllInList)
...
```

This did increase the performance, although now the downstream application has to return more data for a query, so little time increased on downstream side but that's okay.

Now with this, i was able to achieve time as below...
Total records(combined as list , so 1) * No. of service calls(5) * Time per service calls(50 ms as time increased) = 250ms

**But time will grow with the number of service calls.**

**Now i need to parallelize these service calls** and execute these service calls in parallel and update their respective fields on the same product instance (same reference).
Some like below

```
Flux<Product> products = ... // of 10 products
products
.collectList() // Mono<List<Product>>
.doAllInParallel(serviceCall1, serviceCall2, serviceCall3...)

. // get all updated products // flux size of 10
```

With that i want to achieve time... 250/5 = 50ms

How to achieve that?
I found different articles, but i am not sure on what's the best way to do it? Can someone please help me on the same.

Comment: try using `flatMap` instead of `doOnNext`

Comment: flatMap will also block, that won't make calls parallely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked using

```
products // Flux<Product>
.collectList() // Mono<List<Product>>
.flatMap(list -> Mono.zip( this.call1(list) ,this.call2(list) ) ) // will return Tuple
.map(t -> t.getT1) 
.flatMapIterable(i->i)

Mono<Product> call1(List<Product> productList){
   // some logic
}
Mono<Product> call2(List<Product> productList){
   // some logic
}
```

Actually zip and flatmapiterable , all could be done in a single step as well.. here's its just for demo.